# How can I instruct Ubuntu to launch VLC using my integrated (Intel) GPU instead of my default NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, intel, vlc

I have my NVIDIA GPU set as the default within Ubuntu 22.04, since I wasn't able to get my external monitor to work otherwise. However, I am [having trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462490/how-can-i-get-8k-h265-mp4-files-to-play-better-on-vlc) getting VLC to play videos correctly using the NVIDIA card, whereas I found that these same videos play well using my integrated Intel graphics.

Is there a way that I can instruct Ubuntu to use Intel for VLC video playback while keeping NVIDIA as the default graphics card in all other applications?

Comment: Are you using X or Wayland?  How are you setting Nvidia to be the default (selecting power/performance no longer does that)?

Comment: I'm using the default Ubuntu GNOME UI, so I think the answer is X? I set the Nvidia card as the default by following the steps in this guide: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu (ie sudo prime-select nvidia) I wouldn't mind having the Intel card as the default except that my external monitor wasn't displaying an image when I switched over to it.

Comment: x vs Wayland is a choice at login (when password field is displayed, click on gear in lower right corner.). CUDA samples need Nvidia to run, and the prime-select did not fix the problem.  xrandr --listproviders (when runnint X) and ensure Intel (modesetting) is the sink output. Fix for a prog with Env vars __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <prog to run>

Comment: It is not a VLC setting VLC will only use the default video. You need to set the default.

Answer (score 1):

I can do this if I add vlc to the favourites bar (at the bottom of the screen)
Search key (windows)
type vlc
right click vlc's icon
select add to favorites.
then bring up app bar at the bottom
right click vlc icon
launch using discrete graphics card.

as I am a naughty boy and using manually installed drivers,  and I have no idea if it does indeed use the discrete graphics card, and as I am using wayland per echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE , use at your , well, discretion.

actually I just checked and you have that option in your intitial software search choice, you don't need to add it to favorites.

ubuntu 22.04

Comment: this may or not help

https://starbeamrainbowlabs.com/blog/article.php?article=posts%2F436-running-application-on-nvidia.html